# Difference between structured programming and structured approach to development?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm looking for clarification -

The terms 'structured programming' and 'structured development approach' refer to different things. Is this correct?

My understanding is that 'structured programming' is programming which is clear and well set out, using subroutines and modules etc. to keep 'structure' in software. This is different to the 'structured software development approach' which refers to the methodology of completing the stages of development (defining the problem, planning, creating, testing and maintenance) sequentially and not starting one until the previous is finished.

I'm a student and need to have these terms clear. Am I on the right track? Are there any important details I'm missing?

Comment: You might be interested in [Structured programming versus OO programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65116/structured-programming-versus-oo-programming), particularly [uncle bob's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/65175/422811)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track, these are different things.

Both of these terms are very broad. All programming paradigms that have been in use during the last 50 years (procedural, object oriented, functional etc.) are structured. And I would also say that every development methodology (waterfall, v model, agile etc.) is also structured in some way. Of course there are different grades.

Comment: Historically, "structured programming" has an even more specific meaning: not using GOTO. Dijkstra's famous essay on the evils of GOTO prompted language designers to create control structures that allowed programmers to write programs without using GOTO at all. From that we get things like for, while, do, if, switch etc. and later on we get foreach, for..in etc. When languages like C was introduced they were called "structured languages" because they have all the necessary control structures to enable your boss to completely ban you from using GOTO.